# From iCal to JSON then to a HTML/JS Calendar View

Tags: javascript, json, icalendar

I have ical format data and need to generate html from the ical data using js..any experts to guide me? Appreciate your thoughts...

I have stored the .ics data in plain file for now.avascript ruby-on-rails ruby json icalendar

Comment: https://github.com/adrianlee44/ical2json

Comment: Thanks for that ! I have ical data in Json format.. I am looking for how to get only the events that shows in calendar view from the json.... any inputs? as i dont find the any API or rrules works... Thanks